# What consequences could occur if I made a Microsoft account with fake information for privacy reasons?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s, microsoft-store

I bought an Xbox Series S and was forced to open a Microsoft account.

I had to enter

- Last name First name
- Date of birth
- Email address

I filled in all the information with false information, except for the email, where I entered my Protonmail account. The reason is privacy.

I wrote down all the fake information so I can refer to it in the future.

Now I want to buy vouchers in the physical store for buying games. I am afraid that I will lose my purchased games (maybe even the hardware linked to my account) if Microsoft bans me for false information. I am also a VPN user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing that really matters for account and game usage is your email address. I highly doubt Microsoft will do anything to you for putting in fake info, as it's not their problem if you do... it's yours (unless you are stealing someone else's identity, in which case they will act if the real person you are stealing from notices and opens a case).

You will probably face issues with account security and recovery, as setting up things like two-factor authentication requires your actual phone. If your account is hacked, you can't prove it is yours since you will need to provide proof you are the account owner (since this information is faked, any proof you provide will only prove you aren't the "real" owner).